# How to get the highest value from a filtered list? haskell

Tags: haskell

My function basically would work, but I have problems with type definition (it's fix, I can't change it)

```
conditionalMax :: Ord a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
conditionalMax f x = maximum [filter (f) x]
```

the output should be like:

```
conditionalMax even [2,5,9,8,4,2] == Just 8
conditionalMax odd [2,5,9,8,4,2] == Just 9
```

Comment: `maximum` has signature `maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a`, so it does not return a `Maybe a`. You will need to guard against the empty list as well. Note that `[filter (f) x]` will generate a singleton list that contains a sublist, so you are not filtring properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically two major problems here:

1. with `[filter (f) x]` you are creating a *singleton* list: a list that contains exactly *one* element: the filtered list, so it has type `[[a]]`; you probably want to use `(filter f x)` instead; and
2. `maximum :: (Foldable f, Ord a) => f a -> a` does *not* return a `Maybe a`, but an `a`. You thus need to construct a function that first looks if the list is empty, and if not, return a `Just …` that wraps the maximum; otherwise it should return `Nothing`.

You thus probably want to implement a helper function, and then use that function in the `conditionalMax`:

```
safeMaximum :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
safeMaximum = …
```

where you need to fill in `…` yourself.